# Pandas Vlookup 2 DF Columns Different Lengths & Perform Calculation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vlookup, calculation

I need to execute a vlookup-like calculation considering two df's of diff lengths with the same column name. Suppose i have a df called df1 such as:

```
Y     M        P        D
2020  11       Red      10
2020  11       Blue     9
2020  11       Green    12
2020  11       Tan      7
2020  11       White    5
2020  11       Cyan     17
```

and a second df called df2 such as:

```
Y     M        P        D
2020  11       Blue     4
2020  11       Red      12
2020  11       White    6
2020  11       Tan      7
2020  11       Green    20
2020  11       Violet   10
2020  11       Black    7
2020  11       BlackII  3
2020  11       Cyan     14
2020  11       Copper   6
```

I need a new df like `df3['Res','P']` with 2 columns showing results from subtracting df1 from df2 such as:

```
Res     P 
Red     -2
Blue    5
Green   -8
Tan     0
White  -1
Cyan    3
```

I have not been able to find anything with a lookup and then calculation on the web. I've tried merging df1 and df2 into one df but I do not see how to execute the calculation when the values in the "P" column match. I think that a merge of df1 and df2 is probably the first step though?

Answer (score 0):

- Based on the example, column `'Y'` and `'M'` do not matter for the merge. If these columns are relevant, then use a list with the `on` parameter (e.g. `on=['Y', 'M', 'P']`).

  - Currently, only columns `[['P', 'D']]` are being used from `df1` and `df2`.
- The following code, produces the desire output for the example, but it's difficult say what will happen with larger dataframes and if there are repeating values in `'P'`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup the dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Y': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020], 'M': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11], 'P': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Tan', 'White', 'Cyan'], 'D': [10, 9, 12, 7, 5, 17]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Y': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020], 'M': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11], 'P': ['Blue', 'Red', 'White', 'Tan', 'Green', 'Violet', 'Black', 'BlackII', 'Cyan', 'Copper'], 'D': [4, 12, 6, 7, 20, 10, 7, 3, 14, 6]})

# merge the dataframes
df = pd.merge(df1[['P', 'D']], df2[['P', 'D']], on='P', suffixes=('_1', '_2')).rename(columns={'P': 'Res'})

# subtract the values
df['P'] = (df.D_1 - df.D_2)

# drop the unneeded columns
df = df.drop(columns=['D_1', 'D_2'])

# display(df)
     Res  P
0    Red -2
1   Blue  5
2  Green -8
3    Tan  0
4  White -1
5   Cyan  3
```